# How to stop the exposed dropdown menu closing after cancel last letter in the AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android

I need help to change a behavior of exposed dropdown menu in android.
I am looking to find a way to stop the auto-closing of the dropdown menu whene i cancel all the letters that i inserted in the dropdown menu. The desired behavior is to show all the selectable options in that specific case.
The dropdown menu that i implemented is made by using aTextInputLayout and an AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_report"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:hint="@string/report"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_textview_report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The items are passed to the menu by using a custom arrayadapter where is made the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when popup window was closing if I set a new text to AutoCompleteTextView.
Have you tried to use setText() with filter parameter?
Like that:

```
AutoCompleteTextView.setText("", false).
```